# If $f:\ [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is right differentiable at $0$ then $\big|f(x)-f(0)\big|<\alpha x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\,[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be right differentiable at $0$ such that $\big|f'_+(0)\big|<1$. Then
\begin{align}
\exists\alpha\in(0,1),\ \exists\delta>0:\ \big|f(x)-f(0)\big|<\alpha x,\ \forall\, 0<x<\delta.
\end{align}

My attempt :
From the assumption,
\begin{align}
\exists f'_+(0)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0:\ \left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}-f'_+(0) \right|<\epsilon,\ \forall h>0:\ h<\delta.
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}-f'_+(0) \right|&<\epsilon
\\ \Big|f(h)-f(0)-hf'_+(0) \Big|&<\epsilon|h|
\\ \big|f(h)-f(0)\big|-\big|hf'_+(0) \big|&<\epsilon|h|
\\ \big|f(h)-f(0)\big|&<\epsilon|h|+|h|\big|f'_+(0) \big|
\\ &<|h|(\epsilon+1)
\end{align}
Here I have no clue what to do next. Could anyone give me a hint ? Thank.

Comment: Take $\alpha=\big|f'_+(0)\big|+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is so small that $\alpha <1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method of proof by contradiction for this question. If this proposition does not hold, then we have
$$
\forall   \alpha\in(0,1), \forall \delta>0,\exists x\in(0,\delta):|f(x)-f(0)|\ge \alpha x
$$

Hence ,we can take $\alpha$ satisfying $f_{+}^{\prime}(0)<\alpha<1$ ,and we can get a sequence of number $\left \{ x_n \right \} $ satisfying the following condition:

(a). $0<x_{n+1}<x_n$

(b) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n=0$

(c) $\left | \frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}  \right | \ge \alpha$

Note that  $f$ is right differentiable at $0$,which implies that
$$
f_{+}^{\prime}(0)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n}  \right |>f_{+}^{\prime}(0)
$$
This leads to a contradiction.

Ps :The method for constructing sequence $\left \{ x_n \right \} $ is as the following .Taking $\delta_1=1 $,there exists $x_1$ satisfying $x_1<1$.Then,taking $\delta_2=\min \left \{ \frac{1}{2},x_1 \right \}  $,there exists $x_2$ satisfying $x_2<\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_1<x_2$.Continuously repeating the above construction process and taking $\delta_n=\min \left \{ \frac{1}{n},x_{n-1} \right \}  $,there exists $x_n$ satisfying $x_n<\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_n<x_{n-1}$.It can be verified that A satisfies three conditions: (a), (b), and (c).